# Jquery animation problem

Tags: jquery

When making a horizontal accordion using jquery whereby one block element is decreasing in width whilst another is expanding in width - how do you code this so the blocks to the right do not get pulled and pushed during the animation. For sure the reason this is happening is because the increase and decrease in the widths are not and cannot happen at exactly the same time but how can I get around this?

Comment: what do you really want? Avoid the animation in 1 accordion while the other one is animating or avoid the "jump"? The jump can be avoided if the design isn't fluid only.

Comment: I want to avoid the jump. It just looks really bad. The accordion is aligned with other elements so it's overall width can't change

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this works (post your code to test) but you can disable the other accordion when the other is animating.

```
$('#accordion1').bind('accordionchangestart', function(event, ui) {
    $('#accordion2').accordion( "option", "disabled", true );
});

$('#accordion1').bind('accordionchange', function(event, ui) {
    $('#accordion2').accordion( "option", "disabled", false );
});
```